# How to join a list of strings into a single string and the split this single string into some fixed length stringsL strins

Tags: string, python-2.7, list, join, split

I have a list of string :

```
L= ['11010101\n', '10111001\n', '11111001\n', '10111001\n', '101 \n']
```

I want to join this strings first as follows:

```
 L=['11010101101110011111100110111001101']
```

and then split it of fixed length 5 as :

```
L=[ '1101010','1101110','0111111', '0011011','1001101']
```

as well as :

```
L=[ [1,1,0,1,0,1,0],[1,1,0,1,1,1,0],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1], [0,0,1,1,0,1,1],[1,0,0,1,1,0,1]]
```

and

```
L=[ '1101010\n','1101110\n','0111111\n', '0011011\n','1001101\n']
```

My code here:

```
M=[]
L= ['11010101\n', '10111001\n', '11111001\n', '10111001\n', '101 \n']
for i in L:
    M=''.join(L)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `strip()` each of the items then `join()` them:

```
>>> ''.join(x.strip() for x in L)
'11010101101110011111100110111001101'
```

Then you need to chunk it into 5:

```
>>> s = ''.join(x.strip() for x in L)
>>> n = len(s)//5
>>> i = iter(s)
>>> list(iter(lambda: tuple(it.islice(i, n)), tuple()))
[('1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0'), ('1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0'),
 ('0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'), ('0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1'),
 ('1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1')]
```

And finally `join()` them back up with `'\n'`:

```
>>> [''.join(e) + '\n' for e in iter(lambda: tuple(it.islice(i, n)), tuple())]
['1101010\n', '1101110\n', '0111111\n', '0011011\n', '1001101\n']
```